# How to add an object as value for an element using jquery?

Tags: jquery, object, dictionary, element

I have a javascript object which is constructed out of user inputs. The object looks like this:

```
        myObject = {
          abc: val1,
          def: val2
        }
```

I want to insert this object as the value of a html element. Tried something similar to the following to achieve this:

```
        $("#myelementid").val(myObject);
```

When inspecting the value of #myelementid - the value shows up as [object Object].
However, I want the actual map to be shown. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this,

```
JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

The above syntax would display that json object in a string format. Please read this to know something about [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MTHKm/)

---

**Your code:**

```
 myObject = {
          abc: val1,
          def: val2
        }

  $("#myelementid").val(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Comment: @user811433 Yes sure. This was actually introduced in javascript 1.7.   Please see this for your reference, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history

Answer (score 0):

Because your value is currently an object and it has to be converted to a string .Use `JSON.stringify` to convert a JavaScript value to a JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) string.

```
var myObject = {
      "abc": "val1",
      "def": "val2"
    }
$("#myelementid").val(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LzaCG/)